# align labels and inputs hozizontally in sonata admin

Tags: css, symfony, templates, twig

By default in symfony2 labels and input fields are not aligned horizontally, how can i achieve that design by this :

```
{{ form_label(form.titre1) }}{{ form_widget(form.titre1) }}
```

i need that label position on left of the input

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding some simple css, something along the lines of..

```
#form div,
#form label {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it solved by using Bootstrap css for forms and labels